# Adding custom SELECT in ActiveRecord 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgis

I am trying to use the result of a custom query (a distance between two geographical points) as a model attribute. The end goal is to be able to filter and order rows using that column, e.g. :

```
Model.with_distance(point).order(:distance).first
```

I initially thought I could use `select` in a scope ; here is a shorter version without sanitization :

```
scope :with_distance, ->(point) { select("ST_DISTANCE(models.point_in_model, ST_GeographyFromText('#{point.to_s}')) AS distance") }
```

However, that scope only selects the `distance` column, without retrieving model attributes :

```
> Model.with_distance(point)
[#<Model >, #<Model >,...]
```

Adding `models.*` to the `select` call solves the problem, at the cost of forcing the retrieval of the entire row in each query and ignoring other `select` calls.

How can I **add a SELECT clause** instead of **replacing all of them**?

Answer (score 3):

Except for the default `SELECT models.*`, ActiveRecord normally *adds* SELECT clauses, instead of *replacing* them.

```
> Project.select(:id).select(:name)
=> Project Load (0.5ms)  SELECT id, name FROM "projects"
```

Obviously, this doesn't help when you want "the default SELECT, plus any others I ask for."

You might try a `select_star` scope

```
scope :select_star, -> { select("models.*") }
scope :select_star, -> { select(self.arel_table[Arel.star]) } # Arel version, if feeling adventurous
```

which you could use in places where you want all the columns?

```
> Model.with_distance(point).select_star
=> SELECT ST_DISTANCE(models.point_in_model, ST_GeographyFromText('0,0')) AS distance, models.* FROM ...
```

Comment: I have never used it, but Arel sounds interesting. However this forces the developer to add .select_star at the end of most queries, while I would like it to be the same default as Rails... It's easier to prototype queries using the default "select all" approach and then optimize by adding SELECT calls where needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with `select` behaviour. Let's conclude these bad spots:

- by default, when query is being constructed and we never run `select` before, the `Arel.star` is used to fetch all columns.
- Some times we don't want ActiveRecord/ARel to add "*", ex. we are building some intermediate query or query for statistics, and that star just increases a work on our database (and can also affect the ruby callbacks that run on presence of attributes etc).

I think one of solutions (tested on Rails 4.2.4, that also can be easily applied for Rails 3) is to add the following code to your model or ActiveRecord::Base:

#### app/models/item.rb

```
...
# include "items".* by default
default_scope ->{select(arel_table[Arel.star])}
# when we dont want to use all columns
scope :no_columns, ->{except(:select)}
...
```

Now, for example we have the following scope in the app/models/item.rb

```
...
scope :some_business_logic_scope, ->{
    # doing some big query
    joins(...).
    where(...).
    select(...) # some virtual attributes
    # we dont need to run the following line any more
    # select(self.arel_table[Arel.star])
}
...
```

#### Usage

```
Item.select(:id) # selects all columns
Item.no_columns.select(:id) # selects only column id
Item.no_columns.some_business_logic_scope # selects only required columns
Item.some_business_logic_scope # selects all attributes including those added by some_business_logic_scope
```

Comment: `select(arel_table[Arel.star])` and then following it up with another `select` call did what I was looking for, which is essentially "bring me back all of the default fields plus some additional ones I'm defining".